# What's this sentence 麻烦包两份上次的礼盒 mean?

Tags: simplified-characters, learning

I've been googled and using translator what I found that 麻烦包两份上次的礼盒 means is "Please pack two copies of the last gift box". but I'm not satisfied so I searched that 麻烦 is similar with Qing = please, this sentence is about buying two pack bouquet. Can someone tell me the right translation? thank you

Answer (score 2):

份(set/ suit/ ...) is a classifier for 礼盒 (gift box)

两份礼盒 = two sets of the gift box

麻烦 = to trouble (you) = Please

包 = pack

两份 = two sets of

上次的礼盒 = the gift box (I bought) last time

> 麻烦包两份上次的礼盒 = Please, pack me two sets of the gift box I bought last time

When you use 个 as the classifier for 礼盒, e.g. 两个礼盒, you are referring to the box itself

When you use 份 as the classifier for 礼盒, e.g. 两份礼盒, you are referring to all the items (the content) in the gift box, which need to be packed into one set

> *this sentence is about buying two packs of bouquets*.

A bouquet is basically a collection of different flowers packed into one bundle or basket plus a card.

If you meant bouquet instead of gift box, you should write: "Please, give me two of those bouquets I bought last time".

礼盒 (gift box) and 花束 (bouquet) are two different things.